# PHP - Smartest way to access object properties

Tags: php, object, drupal, drupal-modules

So via API I am getting an object back like below:

```
object(stdClass)#11 (3) {
  ["emailAddress"]=>  string(21) "example@example.com"
  ["firstName"]=>  string(5) "John"
  ["industry"]=>  string(8) "Internet"
```

I have simplified the object but properties could also be nested (**FYI its a very large object hence the quest to find the smartest way**). Later on, this property will be assessed. Using line like: `$api->emailAddress`.

Now, API might return all properties all the time so my code break for example if `emailAddress` is not passed by the API. Of course I can use `property_exists()` or `isset()` individually on each property. But I am curious if there is a better practise out there as there are A LOT of property and they can also be nested.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you make a class for this object?

Comment: `array_map` might be useful.

Comment: @Daan even with array map I still need to check for existance of property don't it?